# Getting Error "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string" even though im replacing URL

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs, dashboard

Hey guys i am having an issue with java script and implementing a chart dashboard for my spread sheet. For testing purpose i have followed a tutorial by google to create a chart dashboard using my own spreadsheet. I tried to create a simple chart by substituting the URL address with my own spread sheet URL however this sort of backfired on me as i get this error message "Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"

A copy of the table i am trying to implement into a chart is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10fFAo_MxyLx1apRXiepR91UJXO2KA5ucRx2XB66bc4Q/edit?usp=sharing it form 3 called "Attendance Record" which i want as a chart

[image: screenshot]

so i followed the steps of the first link from google and edited to make sure it links right and points to a selected range of cells but changed the #gid to #gid3 as i read that the number at the end represents what form you are referring to. Then i specified the range at the end of the link by adding &rangeB2:C4 as i only want the name and number columns to be in the chart:

The link below is the one i edited and replaced .

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FOVmfesx7ATNe8qjWjkU2GbjBCBZxL0BRswJv6rcGPs/edit#gid=3&rangeB1:C4

but for some reason it bring up the error message as stated in my question.

Ultimately correct me if i am wrong but i think it is something to do with the URL link i am using because i tried it with another link that they used as an example and it worked. I even copy and pasted the same data they used into my spreadsheet and then copied the url and still it didnt work.

So how do you get the correct link?

Comment: Since the info in the tutorial is important to the context of your question, you should include a link to it.

Comment: Hey there, sorry about that ill be sure to make things clear next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A visualization shouldn't be using an `edit` URL, it should be using the GViz service, like:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq
```

Following that, you include the parameters to obtain your data. Navigating to your "Attendance Record" sheet, you'll find that the `gid=1324373577`. This is a permanent gid; the positional gid (`3`) does not appear to work with the new Google Sheets.

To restrict the data to specific columns and rows, you pass in a query using the [Visualization Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). For the specific cells you're looking at, this would work:

```
tq=select B,C where B <> ""
```

This reads:

- `select B,C...` Pick columns B and C from the spreadsheet. Ignore everything else.
- `... where B <> ""` But only rows that meet this criteria, that the value in column B is not blank.

... and will end up being `B1:C4`.

The resulting URL:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FOVmfesx7ATNe8qjWjkU2GbjBCBZxL0BRswJv6rcGPs/gviz/tq?gid=1324373577&tq=select%20B,C%20where%20B%20%3C%3E%20%22%22
```

Returns this (formatted for readability):

```
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({
  "version": "0.6",
  "reqId": "0",
  "status": "ok",
  "sig": "792390171",
  "table": {
    "cols": [{
      "id": "B",
      "label": "",
      "type": "string"
    }, {
      "id": "C",
      "label": "Number Attended",
      "type": "number",
      "pattern": "General"
    }],
    "rows": [{
      "c": [{
        "v": "David "
      }, {
        "v": 2.0,
        "f": "2"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Chris Hinds"
      }, {
        "v": 1.0,
        "f": "1"
      }]
    }, {
      "c": [{
        "v": "Joe Blog"
      }, {
        "v": 1.0,
        "f": "1"
      }]
    }]
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply this has fixed the problem, you sir have made my day. Not exagerating at all i spent about 6 hours just finding out what was wrong.... I couldn't find any documentation on this at all? where did you find out how to solve the problem, might i ask

Comment: @hero8110 - Thanks, glad to help. Do make sure to add the info about the tutorial you were referring to in your question, to help others in future. This info is pretty much all a repeat of what you'll find in the Query Language Reference, linked in the question. See the section, Setting the Query in the Data Source URL.

Comment: Absolutely, my apologies for not adding that information. I know you have solved my problem but i really want to learn how your query works. I have taken a look at the documentation and used the "encode" and "decode" but if i may ask could you take me through the query you set up in the url. 
http://gyazo.com/57634109537cf57ae35bd292ca1a2926

Comment: Updated, check it out.

Comment: Hey @Mogsdad sorry to trouble you like this but this is really getting stressful getting the google Java script to work and documentation for this is so hard to understand, would it be possible to if you could check out my JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hm7q5peg/ and why it doesnt work . Im really sorry to ask you like this but i just cant take it any more its too stressful.

Comment: I've [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm7q5peg/1/), it somewhat works now. You needed to add Google's jsapi as an external resource, and your query response handling code was doing nothing but error handling, because you had a closing brace too soon. You were trying to put the chart into non-existent `chart_div`.

Comment: Hi sir thank you very much for your help, i dont normally do this but do you have a website i can spare a few change to or do you even take donations for your assistance because you have been a very big help to me and seriously i dont know what i could do to repay you with.

Comment: Also i noticed you changed the link in the js fiddle, why is that? and how did you obtain it?. Really sorry for all the questions

Comment: The only payment we seek here is glory! Once you have enough rep to do so, come back and upvote helpful answers, that's all. WRT the link, I used the format shown in [this doc page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets). The previous one works as well - in fact, it appears just a bit faster, too.